# function depends on difference of arguments

Tags: real-analysis

Given a function $f(x,y)$ that is symmetric in its arguments and also
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 0$$,
does it necessarily follow that $f$ can be considered a function of $x-y$ alone? How does one prove that rigorously?

(my question falls out of trying to understand [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/107141/55817) physics.SE answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [Method of Characteristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics), we get that $f$ is constant on paths where
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=1
$$
That means that there is a function $g$ so that
$$
f(x,y)=g(x-y)
$$

---

**Method of Characteristics**

We are given that
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=0
$$
since
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}t}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t}
$$
we get that $\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}t}=0$ when $\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}=\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t}$.

Answer (score 0):

The solving of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 0$ leads to : $$f(x,y)=F(x-y)$$ where $F$ is any derivable function.

This is equivalent to a sum of functions : $$f(x)=F_1(x-y)+F_2(x-y)+...+C$$ because a constant $C$ belongs to the set of functions $F_k(x-y)$ with $F_n$ the constant function.

Thus, $f$ is a function, or a sum of functions, of $(x-y)$ alone.